# Getting error while configuring default account key for in parse command line tool

Tags: parse-platform, terminal

I am configuring default account key for parse command line tool & my email by command: `parse configure key -d` , but it is showing the following error:

```
`Could not store credentials. Please try again.

Account key ************************************3ouF does not belong to [abc@xyz.com]`
```

Note: I have this account key in my parse account.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem also when I changed my e-mail in my Parse account. I solved this by deleting the file '~/.parse/netrc' and configuring the key again with my new e-mail. Parse stores the credentials in the netrc file and it looks like you can't currently modify it with the command line util. So, to be clear:

1) Delete '~/.parse/netrc' file (In windows, this should be located in your %UserProfile% folder)

2) Run 'parse configure accountkey' (The new configuration will ask for your Parse e-mail and password)

I hope this solves your problem as well.

Comment: It seems they have changed where the keys are stored. No `.parse` folder exists in my user profile directory

Comment: @Isuru, it's a hidden directory on Mac OS.  Use terminal to get to your user directory, then "cd .parse", then "rm netrc" - works like a charm.